# Unable to install pymongo with Anaconda 3 on W10

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, anaconda

I have Python 3.5 and Anaconda 3 installed. Pymongo works fine in Python 3, but I can't get it to install in Anaconda.

```
> conda install pymongo
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ...........
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint:
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%


Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - pymongo
  - python 3.5*

Use 'conda info pymongo' etc. to see the dependencies for each package.

Note that the following features are enabled:
  - vc14
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get pymongo installed in my Anaconda3 + Python 3.5.1 installation. It's possible that it just won't work in your version of Python 3.5 with Anaconda3. I was also able to get it installed in Python 3.4 + Anaconda3.

You can update to the latest version and packages:

```
# On Windows
conda update --prefix C:\Anaconda3 anaconda

# Linux
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

You can also create a new environment in your current Anaconda3 installation.

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

This will download all of the standard Python 3.4 compatible packages from Anaconda and set up a new environment. In a command shell, to use this environment and install pymongo:

```
activate py34
conda install pymongo
```

The path to set in your IDE would then be:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\py34\python.exe
```

You can create multiple Python environments for 2.x/3.x and have packages installed independently.

Documentation:
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html